# Find the case when $t^3$ never equals to any of the given

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $t$ be a real number such that $t^2=at+b$ for some positive integers $a$ and $b$, then for any choice of positive integers $a$ and $b$,  $t^3$ never equals to
a) $4t+3$  b) $8t+5$  c) $10t+3$  d) $6t+5$

I have recognized that if $t=0$ then all the answers are correct.  But can not proceed in case of $t\neq 0$. Please help to solve it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you mean no answers are correct @kingW3

Comment: $t=0$ cannot be correct because $b$ must be positive.

Comment: Correct sir, thank you @Ross Millikan

Answer (score 1):

As an example, $10t+3$ is not the answer.  $t^3=10t+3$ has solutions of $t=\frac 12(3\pm \sqrt{13}),-3$    We have $(\frac 12(3+\sqrt {13}))^2=\frac 12(11+3\sqrt{13})=3\cdot \frac 12(3+\sqrt{13})+1$  and we get $a=3,b=1.$  You should go through the other three and see if one fails.  I suspect that what will fail is $b$ becomes negative.

Answer (score 0):

$$t^3=t(at+b)=at^2+bt=a(at+b)+bt=(a^2+b)t+ab$$

With $a,b$ positive integers, what if $ab=5$ as in part d)? Then $\{a,b\}=\{1,5\}$, and the value of $a^2+b$ is either $6$ or $26$. Since the coefficient of $t$ is part d) is $6$, part d) is viable.

Part c) is similarly viable with $a=3$ and $b=1$.

Part a) is similarly viable with $a=1$ and $b=3$.

But part $b$ would require $\{a,b\}=\{1,5\}$, and then the value of $a^2+b$ cannot be $8$.

Comment: "But part b would require {a,b}={1,5}"  No, it wouldn't.  It would only require $(a^2 + b)t + ab = 8t + 5$ so $t = \frac {5-ab}{a^2 + b - 8}$ (as $a^2 + b - 8\ne 0$).  This would in turn requir that $( \frac {5-ab}{a^2 + b - 8})^2 = a \frac {5-ab}{a^2 + b - 8} + b$ which may or may not be possible.

Comment: @fleablood $t$ is a solution to a monic quadratic with integer coefficients. Therefore $t$ is either irrational (in which case my argument holds as stated) or $t$ is an integer. But solutions to $t^3=8t+5$ are not integers and that is a trivial case to rule out.